# vtkImageData blank cells or blank points using VTK

Tags: c++, vtk

Is it possible to assign certain cells / points of the vtkImageData to be blank? The point is that cca. 90 % of my vtk domain is empty. The vtk files are huge just because they contain a lot of nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using another data structure besides vtkImageData? For sparse points, you could use vtkPolyData.